# List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject on action button in a page from managed package

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

Installed a managed package, which contain simply 2 pages, controllers, styles, scripts etc.
Then created a site using the a page within the package. When i clicked an action button, Received the exception ,

> List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject Error is in
>   expression '{!saveingData}' in page donation:donationform: (Donation)
>   An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been
>   notified. (Donation)

What will be the reason? Anything regarding the installation or configuration.
Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to execute a SOQL query that returns several results and assign the SObject list returned to a single SObject.

Something like this :

```
SObject obj = [SELECT ...]; // But SELECT query return more than one SObject
```

You should do :

```
List<SObject> objList = [SELECT ...];
```